# Using Google Analytics in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, google-analytics-api

I am trying to integrate google analytics in to my silverlight 4 out of browser application. When i add my Google Analytics code in my XAML like the following:

```
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ga:GoogleAnalytics WebPropertyId="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I am getting an error which is 
***"Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection' threw an exception."***

I am not able to find much of a help in the net regarding this, few pointed out at my user control code which is :

xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

currently i am using VS 2010 and Blend 4 for this. 
Thanks for reading this and if you are able to help me out in this issue it would be great.

EDITED:

As Mentioned I am putting the data here:

In my App.xaml

```
<Application   
  x:Class="SilverlightApp.slate.App"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.WebAnalytics;assembly=Microsoft.WebAnalytics"
             xmlns:ga="clr-namespace:Google.WebAnalytics;assembly=Google.WebAnalytics">


    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomControls.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <mwa:WebAnalyticsService>
            <mwa:WebAnalyticsService.Services>
                <ga:GoogleAnalytics WebPropertyId="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
            </mwa:WebAnalyticsService.Services>
        </mwa:WebAnalyticsService>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
</Application>
```

In the Main Page.XAML under the Grid :

```
  <Button x:Name="btn_library_Icon" Margin="86,2,64,6" Style="{StaticResource menu_librarybuttonstyle}" FontFamily="/SilverlightApp.slate;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Segoe UI" FontSize="9.333" Click="btn_library_Icon_Click">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger SourceName="btn_library_Icon" EventName="Click">
                        <mwab:TrackAction Category="Library Accessed"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Image x:Name="image" Source="Assets/icon_menu_library.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="23" Height="23"/>
           </Button>
```

when i run this it gives me an error as :
**"Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerCollection' threw an exception."**

Am i Missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you are running out of browser you have to include something in your app.xaml, like so:

```
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects><mwa:WebAnalyticsService/></Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Also, which version are you running? There was an OOB related bug that was fixed in release 1.4.7:
http://msaf.codeplex.com/discussions/228657

EDIT: I have tried this in a small test app now, and it works fine for me. It throws an exception when trying to set the google WebPropertyID, but that is probably just because I do not have a Google Analytics account myself. Anyway, here is the content of my App.xaml:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.WebAnalytics;assembly=Microsoft.WebAnalytics"
             xmlns:ga="clr-namespace:Google.WebAnalytics;assembly=Google.WebAnalytics"
             x:Class="SilverlightApplication22.App">

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <mwa:WebAnalyticsService>
            <mwa:WebAnalyticsService.Services>
                <ga:GoogleAnalytics WebPropertyId="UA-****-1" />
            </mwa:WebAnalyticsService.Services>
        </mwa:WebAnalyticsService>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And here is a screen shot from my reference list. The referenced version of Google.WebAnalytics is 1.4.6.0 and Microsoft.WebAnalytics is 1.4.3.0. The version of the framework that I installed is 1.4.10.0, just like yours. I guess they have not updated all dlls with the correct version numbers.

[image]

**EDIT 2**: I just tried the button code you posted and the following works fine for me. I can see the requests going off to googleanalytics in Fiddler, and it works both out of browser and in browser. I have added a reference to Microsoft.WebAnalytics.Behaviors, version 1.4.6.0.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication22.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:mwab="clr-namespace:Microsoft.WebAnalytics.Behaviors;assembly=Microsoft.WebAnalytics.Behaviors"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="White">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger SourceName="LayoutRoot"
                            EventName="Loaded">
                <mwab:TrackAction Category="App Loaded" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <Button x:Name="Btn01"
                Click="Btn01_Click">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger SourceName="Btn01"
                                EventName="Click">
                    <mwab:TrackAction Category="Library Accessed" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            Test
        </Button>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: As mentioned in your mail i have added it as following <Application   
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <mwa:WebAnalyticsService>
            <mwa:WebAnalyticsService.Services>
                <ga:GoogleAnalytics WebPropertyId="UA-****-1"/>
            </mwa:WebAnalyticsService.Services>
        </mwa:WebAnalyticsService>
 </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

But it showing an error as Attached property 'Services' not found in type 'WebAnalyticsService'. i am using the latest version 1.4.10

Comment: Thanks for the Info. I have added the Info in the App.xaml file. Now i am trying to add the Trigger event in the Mainpage.xaml and i am getting the following error : "Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerCollection' threw an exception. " 

The Code i have included is as follows:

  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger SourceName="LayoutRoot" EventName="">
       <mwab:TrackAction Category="App Loaded"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>

Comment: It is much better if you edit your original post to include these code samples. Easier to read and easier to follow for anyone else reading this post. Also, it looks like you are missing the EventName in your EventTrigger. I am guessing it should be "Loaded".

Comment: See my "EDIT 2" amendments above.

Comment: @henik, I tried the Edit 2 option and i am still getting the same error. it seems the behavior is creating some problem out there and i am not able to identify it now. i will update you once i get some more input on it. Thanks a ton for you assistance :)

Comment: No problem. I have uploaded my test app here if you want to take a look at it: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7890705/SilverlightApplication22.zip

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, only my project was Silverlight 5.

After much digging around it turned out the project was referencing an old version of the Silverlight toolkit, specifically version 3.

Once I changed that to use SL5 toolkit the issue went away.

Doesn't explain the real reason for the error, but I hope it helps anyway.